# How to find: "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account?"

Tags: support

I realise this has been asked a few times, but I am wondering how do I find out if I can post / my "rating" before I get the error? I can find my Stack Overflow profile.

Tonight I've got the above message & cannot post a new question to Stack Overflow. (I found / find it hard to find questions I know how to answer :)

Though I've found one good query now I answered. Hopefully the person thinks my answer is good.

EDIT: I know I find many similar queries in meta.stackechange, but I can't find a general answer re reading your profile, etc.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you looking for the [post ban FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), or are you looking to find posts you can answer?

Comment: Ah, your edit makes it clear you want to know what posts need improving. The FAQ I linked you to *does* answer that, and how to find your deleted posts.

Comment: That's one thing I'll miss.  If this question were on Stack Overflow's meta, I'd be able to tell you what's wrong if you have deleted posts more easily.